# In Keynote, how to have image mask start with the entire image

Tags: keynote

Frequently when pasting images into Keynote for Mac, I want to crop off a small piece of the image, say on the bottom or the right.

When I apply an image mask, Keynote defaults to a small square inside the image, forcing me to drag the square to the original image boundaries, after which I can crop off the small piece.

It would be much better if the mask were started with the same pixel size as the image, surrounding the entire image.

Is there any way to get it to do so?

Comment: I understand your discomfort in this but from the other hand if the image crop boundary stays at the edge of your pasted image then you might not notice it there, especially on white background.

Comment: I believe this is programmed into the Application and there's no way to alter its behavior. @Tigran raised a valid point. Perhaps a shortcut/gesture to make quickly expand it to all the image would be nice, but I couldn't find such thing.

Comment: I think they could make the marching ants prominent enough that you would notice it. Just seems like a poor design

Comment: Well, this is always a matter of prospective. On the other hand if you are just interested to crop a little bit from the edges why not do it in Apple Preview, save it and then paste it into the Keynote. In Preview you can adjust the crop window as you wish from the beginning. Just a thought ...

Comment: Good idea! Would be nice though if apple just made it work in one application. Thanks!